# Not receiving same OTP in a time step/interval - Django-otp

Tags: python, django, one-time-password, totp

I have set time step as 300sec and TOTP digit as 6. I'm not receiving same OTP in a time step/interval, means receiving different OTP in a given time step. ie, At 2019-11-03 19:15:00, i will get one code; 19:13:00 , i will get another new code.

this is the code:

```
import datetime
import time

from django_otp.oath import TOTP
from django_otp.util import random_hex


class TOTPVerification:

    def __init__(self):
        # secret key that will be used to generate a token,
        # User can provide a custom value to the key.
        self.key = random_hex(20)
        # counter with which last token was verified.
        # Next token must be generated at a higher counter value.
        self.last_verified_counter = -1
        # this value will return True, if a token has been successfully
        # verified.
        self.verified = False
        # number of digits in a token. Default is 6
        self.number_of_digits = 6
        # validity period of a token. Default is 30 second.
        self.token_validity_period = 300

    def totp_obj(self):
        # create a TOTP object
        totp = TOTP(key=self.key,
                    step=self.token_validity_period,
                    digits=self.number_of_digits)
        # the current time will be used to generate a counter
        totp.time = time.time()
        return totp

    def generate_token(self):
        # get the TOTP object and use that to create token
        totp = self.totp_obj()
        # token can be obtained with `totp.token()`
        token = str(totp.token()).zfill(6)
        return token

    def verify_token(self, token, tolerance=0):
        try:
            # convert the input token to integer
            token = int(token)
        except ValueError:
            # return False, if token could not be converted to an integer
            self.verified = False
        else:
            totp = self.totp_obj()
            # check if the current counter value is higher than the value of
            # last verified counter and check if entered token is correct by
            # calling totp.verify_token()
            if ((totp.t() > self.last_verified_counter) and
                    (totp.verify(token, tolerance=tolerance))):
                # if the condition is true, set the last verified counter value
                # to current counter value, and return True
                self.last_verified_counter = totp.t()
                self.verified = True
            else:
                # if the token entered was invalid or if the counter value
                # was less than last verified counter, then return False
                self.verified = False
        return self.verified


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # verify token the normal way
    phone1 = TOTPVerification()
    start_time = time.time()
    expiry_time = time.time() + phone1.token_validity_period
    i = datetime.timedelta(seconds=start_time)
    j = datetime.timedelta(seconds=expiry_time)
    print('Start time:', start_time, str(i))
    print('Expiry time:', expiry_time, str(j))
    while time.time() < expiry_time:
        k = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time())
        generated_token = phone1.generate_token()
        print("Generated token is: {} , current time is :{}".format(generated_token, k))
        time.sleep(35)
```

Result:

```
('Start time:', 1573004969.106607, '18206 days, 1:49:29.106607')
('Expiry time:', 1573005269.106608, '18206 days, 1:54:29.106608')
Generated token is: 400250 , current time is :18206 days, 1:49:29.107410
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:50:04.109554
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:50:39.115040
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:51:14.118708
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:51:49.124145
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:52:24.124820
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:52:59.126073
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:53:34.126536
Generated token is: 219130 , current time is :18206 days, 1:54:09.131970
```

Where i'm doing wrong , did i miss some thing..?

Comment: `totp.time = time.time()` is causing the library to generate a new token each time, no?

Comment: it will set the time to generate a  new token.